# How to get the text from a selected option (not value) with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a select option like this:

```
<label>Choose One:</label>
<select id="choose1">
    <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Then, in my project I can select the necessary option, in the case below, I selected the `val2` value.

```
await page.select('#choose1', 'val2');
```

So, I'm trying to get the text of `val2` but in all the attempts the return is wrong.

I've tryed this, and it returned the textContent of the first option:

```
const element = await page.$('#choose1 option');
const selected = await (await element.getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
```

If I use `await page.$('#choose1 option:selected')`, I get an error that is not a valid selector.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `await page.$('#choose1 option[selected]')`, because `selected` is an attribute, not a state (like `:hover`).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen do you have a runnable, complete example? I don't think `page.select` adds the `selected` attribute to the element.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen this way not works. It happens this error: ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getProperty')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find` on the options to pick the one that matches a particular value, then extract its text content:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0

const html = `
<select id="choose1">
  <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
</select>
`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const targetVal = "val2";

  // not really necessary
  // await page.select("#choose1", targetVal); 

  const selectedText = await page.$$eval(
    "#choose1 option",
    (els, targetVal) =>
      els.find(el => el.value === targetVal).textContent,
    targetVal
  );
  console.log(selectedText); // => Value 2
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: I'm trying this, because it is inside a loop, then I will adapt

Comment: I adapted and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple without puppeteer, you can adapt it.

It will always return the `val2` text, you can change the condition to whatever you need.

```js
const action = () => {
  let optionText = '';
  const optionElements = document
    .querySelectorAll('#choose1 option');

  optionElements.forEach(option => {
    console.log(option.value, option.text)
    if (option.value === 'val2') {
      optionText = option.text;
    }
  });
  document.querySelector('#result').innerText = optionText;
}
```

```html
<label>Choose One:</label>
<select id="choose1">
  <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<div>
  <button onclick="action()">
Click Here
</button>

</div>

<div>
  <label for="result">Result: </label>
  <div id="result" />
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, even without Puppeteer. `optionText` should be the text itself, not a boolean. I recommend adding a browser snippet and fixing the logic. `.find()` is probably the appropriate method here.

Comment: Nope, you can't use `find` on `querySelector` result. It is not a standard `Array`. See the full example.

Comment: You can spread `querySelectorAll` results into an array. That said, the update looks better. Thanks for the fix.